# Selenium WebDriverとはブラウザを操作するものか、それともブラウザ自体？

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

`Selenium WebDrier`というのを今までブラウザそのものではなく、ブラウザを操作するものだと思っていたのですが、Railsのテストでは phantomjs か selenium かを選択する場面があり、ブラウザそのものとして扱われているようです。

公式サイトを読んでみたのですが、いまいちよくわかりませんでした。
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)

Selenium というプロジェクトの中に Selenium WebDriver があるようなのですが、それぞれの分類はどうなっているのでしょうか？

Comment: どうして「phantomjs か selenium かを選択する場面がある」ということが「ブラウザそのものとして扱われている」という解釈になるのかが分かりません。

Comment: phantomjs がHeadlessのブラウザそのものであると認識していたのですが、そこから違っていましたか？

Comment: phantomjsが単独でウェブブラウザの機能を持っているのは確かですが、phantomjs か selenium かというのはテスト用のAPIの選択の問題であって、それがブラウザ自体であるかどうかは関係ありません。

Comment: すいません、やはりよくわからないのですが、phantomjs という用語は「ブラウザそのもの」と「テスト用のAPIの種類」という二種類の意味で使われているということでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium WebDriverを使うには別途ブラウザをインストールする必要があります。ブラウザその物ではありません。

Selenium WebDriverはブラウザをスクリプトで操作する為のドライバで、Selenium WebDriver + ブラウザの組合せで使用します。主にJavaScriptも含めたウェブサイトのテストに使用されますが、ブラウザの画面表示を伴うため、動きが遅いです。

phantomjsはスクリプトで操作可能なヘッドレスブラウザです。画面表示を行わない分高速で、こちらも主にウェブサイトのテストに使用され‌​ます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上のコメント欄の内容と被ってしまうのですがphantomjsがブラウザそのものだけではなく、Selenium WebDriverと同様にその他のブラウザを呼び出す機能も備えているということでしょうか？